# Meteor JS - Multi-Template Javascript

Tags: javascript, meteor

Working with the Meteor.js framework and trying to implement client js (that requires the DOM to be fully loaded) that must be included across multiple templates. To be specific I am using the  hopscotch plugin (https://github.com/linkedin/hopscotch ) which is essentially a website tour plugin. My tour will work across different pages (logically different templates as well.)

I am very much aware of the template.**NAME**.onRendered hook. Since I have more than one template:

```
  template.**NAME1**.onRendered(function(){
    //callTourCode

  })
```

This would not register with template.**NAME2** ... womp womp

Is there any desirable hook to use instead of

Comment: So do you need something to run every time any template is rendered?

Comment: It will run under two conditions:  when a certain boolean flag is false (for a particular user) or when a certain link is clicked (regardless of what the boolean flag is )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [aldeed:template-extension](https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/template-extension) will fit your needs.

Every template `onRendered` callback:

```
Template.onRendered(function () {
  //callTourCode
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. Going to install, once I confirm it works will definitely mark you answer correct my friend :)